# Symbolic Differentiation Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math

So I'm trying to create an algorithm to perform symbolic differentiation to get the exact derivatives of a given function. I've chosen the Reverse Polish Notation to store the expression because it saves me the space and time to build up an actual Expression Tree.
I'll illustrate my problem with a concrete example, and I'll play down my algorithm by hand; so If you expect a simple question or have no clue about the answer please stop read and go away ( I don't need mindless downvotes on this question ).

```
Example:
 Find the derivative of: F=x^3+2*x^2+x
 1) Convert F to RPN form results in: x3^2x2^*+x+
 2) I'll store RPN in stack as follows:
    ---
    |+|
    ---
    |x|
    ---
    |+|
    ---
    |*|
    ---
    |^|
    ---
    |2|
    ---
    |x|
    ---
    |2|
    ---
    |^|
    ---
    |3|
    ---
    |x|
    ---

This is basically the post-order traversal of the expression tree for the F expression. For now I'm focusing on kind of simple derivation rules.

 2) Pop stack (Should be an operator): [+] Rule: op0[+]op1 := d[op0]+d[op1]         -> d[op0]d[op1]+
 3) Get op0 (POP):                     [x] Rule:         x :=          d[x]         -> 1
 4)         APPLY:                     [1]
 5) Get op1 (POP):                     [+] Rule: op0[+]op1 := d[op0]+d[op1]         -> d[op0]d[op1]+
 6) Get op0 (POP):                     [*] Rule: op0[*]op1 := d[op0]*op1+op0*d[op1] -> d[op0]op1*op0d[op1]*+
 7) Get op0 (POP):                     [^] Rule: op1[^]op0 := op1*op0^op1-1         -> op1op0op11-^*
 8) Get op1 (POP):                     [2]
 9) Get op0 (POP):                     [x]
10)         APPLY:                     [1|2|x|2|1|-|^|*]
11) Get op1 (POP):                     [2]
12)         APPLY:                     // How can I apply the multiplication operator now?
```

So if my thought is right, I have the following stack: [2|x|2|1|-|^|*] for the first operand and [2] for the second operand. Now I have to perform [2|x|2|1|-|^|*] [*] [2], which requires me to have this function recursive. Because now I have to perform derivation for [2|x|2|1|-|^|*] also. And in this case I also have to store the results of each operator nodes in different stacks and them merge them in the correct order.

Anyone could recommend a more effective way of doing this?

Comment: Good question. Actually, here is an upvote :) Let's see if I understand you correctly- you are asking if the Polish notation (stack) form can be used to apply symbolic differentiation, or it should be converted to some other representation before doing so ? Interesting :)

Comment: Well let'say you want to do (a*b)' = a'*b + a*b'
Which is ab * in  RPN.
Then, correct me if I am wrong, you have to, in no specific order: 
`pop *
pop a 
apply derivative to a, store result in a'
pop b
apply derivative to b, store result in b'
push +

push *

push a'

push b

push *

push a

push b'
`
Can it be done more effectively ? Not sure.
Is RPN worth it in this case, or should you just use Expression tree ? Good question. However, if all (or almost all) operations in your expression are + and -, you won't need to do all that pushing and popping.

Comment: Well the interesting part would be how to store the inital results, because as you can see over the example they must be resusable but also accessible. For the [*] operator I have to use the result of [^] operator. This leads me to the fact that its not a good idea to store the result directly in an output stream. Else how would I call the function recusrively for the result of [^]? But then again, I need to find a way to effectively access those that I actually need.

Comment: Isn't this just differentiation of polynomials which is pretty trivial handle?

Comment: Yes, the example. Plus these functions to be implemented: sin, cos, tan, ctg, ln, exp, sqrt

Comment: if you include other functions you need to decide whether or not you want to simplify. E.g. (x exp(x) + exp(x))' = exp(x) + x exp(x) + exp(x) = 2exp(x) + x exp(x).

Comment: As the previous comments suggest, it is not possible to tell what is the most effective internal representation without knowing the use case. For large expressions or deep differentiation it is still a field of active research. A well known company has published in 2012 patent US 8149240 B2 on that specific topic.

Answer (score 0):

For simple polynomials, I liked the idea of finding a really short regex solution, but it turned out longer than I hoped...(JavaScript example):

```
function dx(dt){
  dt = dt.replace(/\s+/g,"");

  var signs = dt.match(/[+-]/g) ? dt.match(/[+-]/g) : [],
      dts = dt.split(/[+-]/).map(function(x){
        return x.replace(/([0-9]+)?(\*)?([a-zA-Z])?(\^)?([0-9]+)?/,
          function(z,a,b,c,d,e){
            if (!c){
              return "0";
            }
            a = a ? Number(a) : 1;
            if (!e){
              return "" + a;
            }
            e = Number(e);
            return "" + (e*a) + "*" + c 
                      + (e - 1 > 1 ? d + (e - 1) : "");
        });
      });

    return dts.map(function(v,i){ 
             return v + (signs[i] ? " " + signs[i] : "");
           }).join(" ").replace(/\s\+\s0|0\s\+\s/g,"");
}

console.log(dx("x^3+2*x^2+x"));
console.log(dx("12x"));
console.log(dx("6"));
```

Output:

```
"3*x^2 + 4*x + 1"
"12"
"0"
```